# Main function not found when running Allegro 5 on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, allegro, allegro5

I am trying to get a minimal example of Allegro running on OSX.

I installed the stable version Allegro 5.2 using Homebrew, [as specified in the Allegro wiki](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Installing_with_homebrew).

Here is my code (`allegro.hpp`):

```
/*
 * This program uses the Allegro game library to display a blank window.
 *
 * It initializes the display and starts up the main game loop. The
 * game loop only checks for two events: timer (determined by the FPS)
 * and display close (when the user tries to close the window).
 *
 * http://www.damienradtke.org/building-a-mario-clone-with-allegro
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

constexpr float FPS = 60.0f;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
  ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
  ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = NULL;

  bool running = true;
  bool redraw = true;

  // Initialize allegro
  if (!al_init()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize allegro.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Initialize the timer
  timer = al_create_timer(1.0f / FPS);
  if (!timer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create timer.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Create the display
  display = al_create_display(640, 480);
  if (!display) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create display.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Create the event queue
  event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
  if (!event_queue) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create event queue.");
    return 1;
  }

  // Register event sources
  al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
  al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));

  // Display a blank screen
  al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(100, 149, 237));
  al_flip_display();

  // Start the timer
  al_start_timer(timer);

  // Game loop
  while (running) {
    ALLEGRO_EVENT event;
    ALLEGRO_TIMEOUT timeout;

    // Initialize timeout
    al_init_timeout(&timeout, 0.06);

    // Fetch the event (if one exists)
    bool get_event = al_wait_for_event_until(event_queue, &event, &timeout);

    // Handle the event
    if (get_event) {
      switch (event.type) {
        case ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER:
          redraw = true;
          break;
        case ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE:
          running = false;
          break;
        default:
          fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported event received: %d\n", event.type);
          break;
      }
    }

    // Check if we need to redraw
    if (redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue)) {
      // Redraw
      al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(100, 149, 237));
      al_flip_display();
      redraw = false;
    }
  } 

  // Clean up
  al_destroy_display(display);
  al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my build and execute command:

```
$ clang++ -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -lallegro -lallegro_main allegro.hpp -std=c++14 && ./a.out
```

And here is the error I recieve:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __al_mangled_main
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/allegro/lib/liballegro_main.5.2.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/allegro/lib/liballegro_main.5.2.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have already tried the solution given elsewhere:

1. Change the main-function's signature to `int main(int argc, char** argv)`
2. Link `liballegro_main.dylib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named it `allegro.hpp`, even though it is a **source file**, not a **header file**.

Rename it to `something.cpp` or `something.cc`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Why does it make a difference? Does the compilation process change for different file extensions?

Comment: Yes and no. Compilation changes for different file types. File types are usually determined by file extensions. I think you can tell `clang` what is a header file and what is a source file, but I've never done that and neither should you. That's what extensions are for. What you do, when you compile a header file is create a [precompiled header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header), not an executable. If you don't add the `-o` switch you should normally see a file like `allegro.hpp.gch` or `allegro.pch` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you renamed the file as suggested to *allegro.cpp* then this would be the build process, using make

```
obj =  allegro
CPPFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib
LDLIBS += -lallegro
LDLIBS += -lallegro_main

.PHONY: all
all : $(obj)

allegro: allegro.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you want to use cmake ...

This should get you going

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(hi)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
# These are where the include files should be
include_directories(/usr/local/include)

# add extra lib directories
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

add_executable(hi audio2.cpp)

# specify the dependency on an extra library
target_link_libraries(hi allegro allegro_main allegro_acodec allegro_audio)
```